# SQL - Updating rows in table based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm kinda newbie in SQL and I have to create a request to update multiple rows in table based on multiple conditions.

From this example:

```
id email                 organisationid    principaluserid role
1  john@smith.com        MULT              null            100
2  john@smith.C-100.com  C-100             1               25
3  john@doe.com          MULT              null            100
4  john@doe.C-101.com    C-101             3               50
5  john@doe.C-102.com    C-102             3               25
6  jessica@smith.com     C-102             null            25
```

The goal is to update all the entries from the User table where organisationid equals 'MULT' and who have only 1 principaleuserid match.

From the example above, the first 2 entries match my conditions.
I need then to replace the id=2 email (john@smith.C-100.com) with the one from id=1 email (john@smith.com).

To do the job step by step, I tried to retrieve all the entries that match my condition with this request:

Edit from @The_impaler answer:

```
SELECT * FROM User a1 WHERE a1.organisationid = 'MULT' AND (
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User a2 WHERE a2.principaluserid = a1.id
) = 1;
```

But i'm still bugging on the way to update the entries. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `COUNT()` twice. You can do: `SELECT * FROM User a1 WHERE a1.organisationid = 'MULT' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User a2 WHERE a2.principaluserid = a1.id) = 1`

Comment: @TheImpaler: Indeed, ty. Working better now. That solved my request about quering all the matched entries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, an `update` should do the trick:

```
update user u
    set u.email = um.email
    from user um
    where um.id = u.principaluserid and
          um.organizationid = 'MULT' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from user up2
                      where up2.principaluserid = u.principaluserid and
                            up2.id <> u.id
                     );
```

Comment: Hello, ty for your help. But seems the request have a typo or something else. I have a ' missing FROM-clause entry for table "up" ' from the "up.email" .

Answer (score 0):

You could use an update based on join

```
UPDATE user u1
SET u1.email =  u2.email
FROM user u2 
WHERE u2.organisationid = 'MULT' 
       AND u1.id = u2.principaluserid
```

and if you need  only the value that have only a single principaluserid 
the you could use

```
UPDATE user u1
  SET u1.email =  u2.email
FROM user u2 
INNER JOIN 
(
      select principaluserid , count(*)
      from user 
      group by principaluserid 
      having count(*) =1
    ) t2 ON t2.principaluserid = u2.principaluserid 
    AND  u2.organisationid = 'MULT' 
      AND u1.id = u2.principaluserid
```

Comment: Hello and thanks. But i need to update only the entries where principaluserid matching length = 1 .

Comment: @MrPotatoe  answer  updated .. hope is what you are looking for

Comment: i'm gonna give it a try ;)

Comment: Seems there is a typo on the cont(*)  => COUNT(*) .
But have issues on the "u2.principaluserid" who does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @The_impaler advice, I did this query that seems to answer my need:

```
UPDATE user u1 
  SET organisationid = (SELECT u2.organisationid FROM user u2 WHERE u1.id = u2.principaluserid),
  WHERE u1.organisationid = 'MULT' AND 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user u2 WHERE u2.principaluserid = u1.id) = 1;
```